# Converting a float* or other pointer to unsigned char*

Tags: c++

I have  the following function that takes an array of bytes as an `unsigned char*` of float data.

```
void expectsFloatData(unsigned char* floatData, int floatCount)
{
    //Does something
    memset(floatData, 0, floatCount * sizeof(float));
}

float data[4];
expectsFloatData(???, 4);
```

Does this justify the use of `reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(data);`?
Since I'm just changing the type of the variable as seen by the compiler I shouldn't need to worry about how it will interpret the data in context of an actual character (little endian vs big endian and other platform specific things) as the bytes for the floats are still there, right?

Comment: If you just want to set the floats to 0.0, you can use `float data[4] = {};` or use `std::fill` which is safer than memset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `reinterpret_cast` is the appropriate tool here.  It would be even better if the function parameter were `float*` or `void*` (for example, `void*` is what `memset` uses, to be able to accept and overwrite buffers of any type).

Comment: But is memset the appropriate tool here? Why memset floats?

Comment: @NeilKirk: I'm referring to the example in the question.  The comment "does something" suggests that what's actually going on is not exactly memset.  OP will have to decide whether my comments about memset apply to not-exactly-memset.

Comment: In this case memset was just an example of how the data might be used (to show that it's just being used as an arbitrary array of bytes not specific to floats). I guess it was a little artificial in the example. In reality I have no control over the original function parameters or the implementation.